# Setting no tab after autocomplete, vim

Tags: vim, autocomplete, tabs

Whenever I try to do an auto complete in vim with control-n, after i choose a word it automatically goes to a new line and indents a bunch of spaces. Is there any way to change it so it will just go to the end of the word im typing as opposed to a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the behavior in most IDEs, you don't select a completion candidate from the popup menu with <kbd>Enter</kbd>; you use `<C-Y>`, or just continue typing. See `:help popupmenu-keys`.

You can change the default behaviour, though. Have a look at [Make Vim completion popup menu work just like in an IDE](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Make_Vim_completion_popup_menu_work_just_like_in_an_IDE) for instructions.

Comment: hmm, funny enough it wont let me use control y, if i continue typing it wont complete it, weird! (Figured it out, that was insert mode, it works otherwise)